# Deleting all files and folders except a file using batch

Tags: batch-file

Making a batch file that deletes all files in current dir and then shuts computer down.
Using this to delete -

```
set folder="%CD%"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

Problem is .bat deletes itself and doesn't execute shutdown command.
I have to make sure all files AND folders AND shortcuts are deleted.

Also tell me if there is another way to delete all files on the desktop. I want this program to work on another computer, which means I can't use -

```
delete C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\*
```

although even this doesn't delete all folders.

Comment: Why do you change to the current directory?? Anyway, you could check out the [`if` command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) to exclude from the deletion the current batch file's path which can be retrieved by [`%~nx0`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)...

Comment: @aschipfl Want to delete all files on desktop. Please answer if you have a better way.

Comment: You are already in the *current* directory, so you do not have to change to it, that is what I wanted to point out. I suppose you want to change to the directory where your batch file is located; if so use `cd /D "%~dp0."`. To implement the exception I already hinted...

Comment: No shutdown can be invoked because your script does not have a command that does so. Please post the rest of your script content in your question, or at least enough of it so that your question doesn't remain ambiguous and difficult for us to provide you with pertinent help. If you enter `delete /?` at the command prompt, you'll see why it doesn't work! If you type `erase /?` or `del /?` you'll not see anything about it deleting folders, which you should know because you've already shown that you know about the `RmDir` command.

Comment: There is an environmental variable you can use to get the current users profile directory which will help you navigate to the users desktop folder.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with something like

```dos
<"%~f0" rmdir . /s /q
```

This is just a recursive directory deletion starting in the current active directory (first change to the required one), but as we have an active redirection on the batch file it can not be deleted.